# When semi-simple subcategories "extend" to hearts of t-structures?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, triangulated-categories, abelian-categories, t-structure

Let $A$ be a semi-simple abelian subcategory of a triangulated category $C$ that "generates" $A$ (that is, $C$ equals its own smallest triangulated subcategory that is closed under direct summands and contains $A$), and assume that there are no $C$-extensions  of negative degrees between objects of $A$ (that is, no non-zero $C$-morphisms $X\to Y[i]$ for $X,Y\in A$ and $i>0$).

Under which assumptions it is known that $A$ lies in the heart of a bounded $t$-structure on $C$? I am interested in rather "general" formulations; something similar to Theorem 7.1 of  Keller B., Nicolas P., Weight structures and simple dg modules for positive dg algebras // Int. Math. Res. Not., vol. 2013(5), 2013, 1028–1078 (this is Theorem 8.1 at https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5904). I have met the term "simple-minded collection" in this context (Definition 3.2 of Koenig S.,  Yang D., Silting Objects, Simple-Minded Collections, t-Structures and Co-t-Structures for Finite-Dimensional Algebras// Doc. Math. 19 (2014), 403-438; however, I am not much interested in "very concrete" derived categories).

Comment: Not an answer, but just some articles that seem related: "Hao Su, Dong Yang: From simple minded collections to silting objects via Koszul duality https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.03767" and "Peter Jorgensen: Abelian subcategories of triangulated categories induced by simple minded systems https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.11799"

Comment: Thank you. I have not read these papers - at least, recently.:)